# I neither see the label on the button nor see it painted in green. Why is that ?

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent

The following code places a button onto the panel. But there is a problem.I neither see the label `Click Me` on the button nor I see the button painted in `green`. Why is that ?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Tester extends JButton {

        public Tester(String label) {
            super(label);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            JFrame fr = new JFrame();
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            JButton button = new Tester("Click Me !");
            p.add(button);
            fr.add(p);
            fr.setVisible(true);
            fr.setSize(400,400);    
            fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't override the paintComponent() method of a component to change a color. Instead you should be invoking the `setBackground(...)` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

This will paint all child components. However, custom painting is unnecessary here as `JButton` provides a method [setBackground](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29) to set the background color directly. You can use

```
button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
```

See: [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: what is this call meant for ? Can you please elaborate a bit

Comment: It's used to set the background color of the component. No need to override `JButton` here to give you this functionality

Comment: Also I was testing something else where custom painting is necessary

Comment: I asked for the call `super.paintComponent`

Comment: The paintComponent(...) method paints the component, that is the background, the text, the icon, the borders etc. If you don't invoke the default painting behaviour of the component you get nothing.

Comment: ...that is `super.paintComponent(...)` :)

Comment: @camickr But why do I have to again call the `paintComponent` viz. `super.paintComponent` ?

Comment: What do you mean again call paintComponent()? You didn't call it the first time because you wrote a custom method to change the code of the paintComponent() method. If you also want the default behaviour you need to invoke super.paintComponent(). This is basic Java programming and nothing special to do with painting. I suggest you get a book on Java and do some reading to learn the basics.

Comment: @camickr Consider this : When I instantiate like `JButton b = new Tester()`, the overriden method in _Tester_ i.e `paintComponent` automatically gets called.The statements inside (that paint the button) get executed.At the end when a statement like `super.paintComponent` is encountered it calls the default implementation of `paintComponent` given in the `JComponent` class. Is it so ?

Comment: @camickr okay. What does the default implementation actually do ?

Comment: I give up, I'm not going to repeat myself.

Comment: @camickr I asked this because [even if I comment that call](http://i47.tinypic.com/2jfyqyq.jpg) I get [my button the way I wanted](http://i49.tinypic.com/veam1t.jpg). But if I uncomment `super.paintComponent` I [get this](http://i49.tinypic.com/29elmcy.jpg). This is what I do not understand. What is happening ?

Comment: Your question was: `.I neither see the label Click Me on the button nor I see the button painted in green.` We have explained why.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to call: super.paintComponent(g); in paintComponent() if you want to override any of its behavior.   But if you want just change the background color then do that in your constructor.  There is no need to override paintComponent for a property change.

Comment: -1, answer by Reimeus stated a call to super.paintComponent() was required. My comment stated you should use setBackground(...). No need to repeat suggestions.